# Visual studio code not running any flutter commands

Tags: flutter, cmd, visual-studio-code

I just started mobile app development and i want to use visual studio code but the problem is it does not execute any flutter commands that i run.

Not even flutter --version works but all the flutter commands work when i run them on the cmd.

I tried creating project using vscode and i left it for almost two hours and when i got back it was still the same like on the image below. What could be the problem?

[image]